# Add all 301 redirected sites to Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect

I have one canonical web site, http://example.com.  I also got the .net and .org, domains, so I have 301 redirected all the following to my canonical web site:

```
http://www.example.com
http://example.net, http://www.example.net
http://example.org, http://www.example.org
```

In Google Webmaster Tools, I specified http://example.com as the preferred domain.

All of the above works fine.  Now the question:

The instructions for Google Webmaster Tools implies that I should register all six sites with Google Webmaster Tools.  I would think that registering the one canonical web site is adequate.  Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the current situation and on what you want to do with it.

If `.net` and `.org` have no pages indexed in Google and you're not planning to have any indexed it's fine as is. No need to add your non-canonical domains to Google Webmaster.

But if the `.net` and `.org` domains have already been indexed and you want to redirect this and indicate to Google that `.com` is your canonical domain name now it's a good idea to also register the .net and .org domains. With that you can let Google know that `.com` is the domain name it should show.

See also my answer here: [SEO much better for domain that 301s to other](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69916/seo-much-better-for-domain-that-301s-to-other/69924#69924)